# Value assignments in C

Tags: c

This is a basic C programming question

What does the following declaration do?

```
int * doorptr, * doorlimit = is_open + NUM_DOORS;
```

I thought it assigned the same values to *doorptr and doorlim so I tried to print the following to see:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_DOORS 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int is_open[NUM_DOORS] = { 0 };
    int * doorptr, * doorlimit = is_open + NUM_DOORS;

    printf("doorptr: %p\n doorlimit: %p\n", doorptr, doorlimit);
    printf("*doorptr: %d\n *doorlimit: %d\n", *doorptr, *doorlimit);

    return 0;
}
```

but the output is:

```
doorptr: 0xb777ec20
doorlimit: 0xbf86c0d0
*doorptr: 0
*doorlimit: -1217134592
```

Comment: Note, that not only `*doorlimit` is UB, but also is `*doorptr` (`is_open + NUM_DOORS` points one past the last element of `is_open`).

Comment: Don't dereference `doorlimit`, since it points beyond your array dereferencing it will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: `doorptr` : uninitialize pointer : trash value. `doorlimit` : address of `is_open[100]` : `&is_open[100]`. `*doorptr` : trash value : UB, `is_open[NUM_DOORS]` : The next value of the range of the array : trash value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int * doorptr, * doorlimit = is_open + NUM_DOORS;
```

The above statement means

```
int * doorptr;
int * doorlimit = is_open + NUM_DOORS;
```

The assignment is done only for `doorlimit.` So you don't get same values for both.

Answer (score 3):

This leaves the variable `doorptr` uninitialized. It happens that in your test the value of `doorptr` was a valid pointer to somewhere or other, but in general anything could happen.

Initializing both variables to the same value wouldn't fit in with the rest of the language: it could only make sense here because the two variables happen to have the same type.

Make sure to activate the useful warnings on your compiler. Any halfway decent compiler will warn you if a variable is used without being initialized.

Comment: You could add, that e.g. Gcc needs optimizations to be turned on to do the analysis necessary to see usages of possibly uninitialized variables. Anyway, +1 for mentioning that this could have been answered by a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In this declaration

```
int * doorptr, * doorlimit = is_open + NUM_DOORS;
```

`doorptr` is not initialized. The initializer initializes only `doorlimit`. And the interesting thing is that your program invokes **undefined behavior** because you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer `doorptr` and `doorlimit` is pointing to unitialized location.